# How to inject Network module like this?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I cannot think how to inject Network module.I try and find many way to inject network module in dagger 2.But I  cannot solve this.Please help me.

```
abstract class BaseRepository protected constructor() {
    init {
        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logger)
            .build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Gson()))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

        mTheApi = retrofit.create<AttendanceApi>(AttendanceApi::class.java)
    }
}
```

I try this module but this didn't work.

```
class NetworkModule {
    companion object {
        private const val NAME_BASE_URL = "NAME_BASE_URL"
    }

    @Provides
    @Named(NAME_BASE_URL)
    fun provideBaseUrlString()=
        "http://attendance.saltcloudserver.com/api/"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpClient()=OkHttpClient()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()
    }
}
```

I expect the output but I cannot inject this.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Don't forget to add NetworkModule in `@Component `

Comment: How are you trying to inject this? To begin with, you need to annotate your module class with `@Module`. 

You should provide how you are building the dependency tree with your `NetworkModule` and how you are trying to inject it to be able to say something relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make dagger identify you need to specify that it is `Module`. For that you need to add `@Module` annotation to the class, which I see is missing in your current implementation.

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {
        companion object {
            private const val NAME_BASE_URL = "NAME_BASE_URL"
        }

        @Provides
        @Named(NAME_BASE_URL)
        fun provideBaseUrlString()=
            "http://attendance.saltcloudserver.com/api/"

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideHttpClient()=OkHttpClient()

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideRetrofit(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
            return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build()
        }
    }
```